# Adding multiple nodes to Elastic Search Cluster deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I recently completed a deployment of Elastic Search Cluster on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) using the link mentioned below.

The elastic search works perfectly fine and all operations associated with elastic search are functional, I have two questions associated with this deployment:

1. How many simultaneous search this elastic search can perform? (Considering the fact machine has 1cpu core and 3.75 GB memory)
2. And can we add more nodes with more compute power in later phases? Is there any way I can add more nodes to the cluster as my application scales?

[Google Cloud Bitnami ElasticSearch](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/elasticsearch)

Comment: You can add nodes: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/elasticsearch/#how-to-add-nodes-to-an-elasticsearch-cluster

Comment: @blueCat Thanks for the comment, to clarify more on this once we connect this node, will all previous data will be replicated and stored in this new node too?

Comment: It may, depending on how you configure the nodes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html